# How to minimize all but the current window with batch/powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I want to minimize every window except the current one.

Yea, Yea, 
[cmd / powershell: minimize all windows on your desktop except for current command prompt (console) or except for some particual window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075247/cmd-powershell-minimize-all-windows-on-your-desktop-except-for-current-comman) has an answer, but it only works with nircmd. However, I want this to work on devices without nircmd.exe

How do I this?

A small batch script would be nice, though powershell is allowed.

Comment: I would consider the ToggleDesktop API and then "restore" my own window.   But can a powershell script control its own window to execute the restore?

Answer (score 1):

I used this guys [Set-WindowStyle](https://gist.github.com/jakeballard/11240204) function, minimizing everything but the process running the script:

```
$self = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess()
Get-Process | ? { $_.Id -ne $self.Id } | % {
   Set-WindowStyle -Style MINIMIZE -MainWindowHandle $_.MainWindowHandle
}
```